# Missing color option at layout components in both App Inventor 2 offline versions (AI2U and AILiveComplete) for Windows

Tags: android, layout, background-color, app-inventor

I've currently tried out the two offline versions of App Inventor 2 for android, thus AI2U and AlLiveComplete.

What I found out to my regret, is that in this windows build, there is no color option for the background, both in designer and blocks,  as it is for the Mac version, and particularly for the ALiveComplete.

If anyone know why this is happening, please replay. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The main App Inventor version is provided by MIT online, which is this link http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/

There is the offline version of **AiLiveComplete** and **AI2U**, both are a 1:1 copy of the MIT version without additional features. The main advantage is, that you do not need internet connection and you can build larger projects (> 5 MB). The disadvantage is, it takes time for the guys to build a new version, so the offline version is not always identical with the current MIT version. Therefore if you use one of these personal server, make sure, you use the most recent one, this will be the version most similar to the current MIT version.

- [Ai2LiveComplete by Hossein](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Failivecomplete%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGMI_tAhSBaHWMyoxCzRNbQSc5L5w)
  in case of questions, please ask in the the [AiLiveComplete forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/apptomarket)
- [AI2 Ultimate by krupong](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fai2u%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGdlmVU_IDOPJ-0Fk6E1FKMmscR6g)
  in case of questions, please ask in the [Ai2U forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ai2u)

The latest version of AI2U was created in August 2015, the latest version of AiLiveComplete was created in December 2015. The features you are talking about have been added in September 2015 into MIT App Inventor, see also the [Release Notes](http://appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/ReleaseNotes.html). Therefore this still is not available in AI2U, but should be available in AiLiveComplete. You have to wait, until a new version of a AI2U is released or build your own personal server using the [App Inventor Sources](http://appinventor.mit.edu/appinventor-sources).

Comment: Hi Taifun. The feature to add color in the H & V Layout in AiLiveComplete for Mac (Sept 2015 build) is there and it is working fine. This feature is missing when running offline server for Windows (krupong's). Do you happen to come across this somehow?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)